# How can three double quotation marks be stored in a Python docstring?

Tags: python, double-quotes, docstring

I have a large ASCII logo that I want to store in a docstring. This logo features multiple instances of three consecutive double quotation marks. The size and complexity is such that escaping individual characters isn't a realistic option. Given that at no point is an instance of three consecutive double quotation marks in isolation on a line, how can this logo be stored in a docstring?

Here is a minimal example:

```
logo = """
hello"""world
"""
```

The resulting error is as follows:

```
    hello"""world
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the single-quotes.

```
logo = '''
hello"""world
'''
```

If you don't want to violate PEP8, you can be a bit hackish

```
logo = """
hello'''world
""".replace("'", '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "violate" PEP8 and use `'''`:

```
logo = '''
       hello"""world
       '''
```

Answer (score 0):

I seems backslashes work as well

```
>>> """ \"\"\" """
' """ '
>>>
```